# How to open mulitple streams explicitly in OKHttp client connection

Tags: okhttp, http2

I am using OkHTTP client to access HTTP/2 server. I have a use case where I want to open multiple streams over same connection.

I am using following code to create OkHTTP client.

```
ConnectionPool connectionPool = new ConnectionPool(5,
                CONNECTION_POOL_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectionPool(connectionPool)
                .build();
```

This client can have 5 open connection in the connection pool.
Now I want to make following requests using above client,

```
okHttpClient.newCall(request1.build()).execute()
okHttpClient.newCall(request2.build()).execute()
```

And I want these requests as a separate stream over the same connection, instead of a new connection. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OkHttp will automatically use the same socket for your requests if they’re eligible. The requests need to be HTTPS, the server needs to support HTTP/2, and your code must run on Android 5+ or Java 9+.

Comment: Thanks Jesse for your answer. I wanted to understand more about this eligibility criteria only. It would be great if you can point me to documentation or code for this logic. Also I am using ALPN with JDK-8(-Xbootclasspath).

Comment: The documentation on what’s eligible is pretty limited. There’s a [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44600875/40013) and that’s about it. One challenge is that the eligibility criteria are implementation details that change over time: a future release may drop ALPN support after Java 9 is proven. Connection coalescing can happen, and we can improve its coverage.

Answer (score 0):

OkHttp will use the same connection for the unique server address. And the requests send over that connection will be consumed in a new stream every time.